# Can I use Firebase Push Notifications with Uno Platform?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, uno-platform

Is it possible to use Firebase Push Notifications with the Uno Platform? There are some samples on how to do this with Xamarin Forms, but I could not find anything specific to Uno Platform (or MAUI for that matter).

Comment: Yes, the same documentation for xamarin will apply to uno platform and maui. Uno and Xamarin use the same nuget packages for firebase.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

The iOS and Android heads of Uno Platform apps are the same as classic Xamarin apps.
You can setup push notifications the same way you would with a regular Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android with the SDK of your choice (like Firebase, OneSignal, etc.).